# Behaviour of polylogarithm at $|z|=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, polylogarithm

I have the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (n \theta)}{n^5} = \dfrac{\text{Li}_5 (e^{i\theta}) + \text{Li}_5 (e^{-i\theta})}{2},
$$
where $0\leq\theta < 2 \pi$ is an angle and $\text{Li}_5(z)$ is a polylogarithm function. I want to know the dominant behaviour of my function. I mostly care for the regime $\theta \ll 1$. Could someone please help me find some information on this? I've mostly been only able to find behavours for $z \approx 0$ and for $|z|<1$, which are not my case!

Comment: For real $\theta$ your function seems to evaluate fairly close to $\cos(\theta)$ (see [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7B1%2F2+%28PolyLog%5B5%2C+E%5E%28-I+%5C%5BTheta%5D%29%5D+%2B+PolyLog%5B5%2C+E%5E%28I+%5C%5BTheta%5D%29%5D%29%2C+Cos%5B%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D%7D%2C+%7B%5C%5BTheta%5D%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%5D)).

Comment: $\theta=0$ corresponds to $z=1$ which is where the polylogs conventionally have a branch point, which may be the source of your difficulty. On the other hand, if $S(\theta)=\sum_nn^{-5}\cos(n\theta)$, then we can see directly that $S \sim \zeta(5)-\theta^2\frac{\zeta(3)}{2}$ as $\theta\to 0$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. The quartic term cannot be obtained as easily. These first two terms are very close to the expansion of $\cos$ because $\zeta(5)$ and $\zeta(3)$ are numerically 'close' to unity

Comment: @GabrielYbarraMarcaida Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to tick it. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations) that
$$
\operatorname{Li}_5 ({\rm e}^\mu  ) =  - \frac{1}{24}\mu ^4\log ( - \mu ) + \frac{{25}}{{288}}\mu ^4  + \sum\limits_{k = 0,k \ne 4}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta (5 - k)}}{{k!}}\mu ^k } 
$$
for $\left| \mu  \right| < 2\pi$, $\mu\neq 0$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{{n^5 }}}  = \operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{Li}_5 ({\rm e}^{ - {\rm i}\theta } )) =  - \frac{1}{24}\theta ^4\log \theta & + \zeta (5) - \frac{{\zeta (3)}}{2}\theta ^2  + \frac{{25}}{{288}}\theta ^4 \\ & + \sum\limits_{k = 3}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{\zeta (5 - 2k)}}{{(2k)!}}\theta ^{2k} } 
\end{align*}
for $0<\theta<2\pi$.